# i have an issue with my Code which converts infix to postfix

Tags: c++, runtime-error, postfix-operator, infix-operator

Any expression that contains ( like (5+6) a runtime error occurs don't know why ... i traced the program a lot but couldn't find the error ... my code :

```
int main() {
    string infix, temp = "";
    cin >> infix;
    stack<char> S;
    for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++){
        if (infix[i] == '+' || infix[i] == '-' || infix[i] == '*' || infix[i] == '/'){
            if (!S.empty() && priority(S.top()) <= priority(infix[i])){
                while (!S.empty()){
                    temp += S.top();
                    S.pop();
                }
            }
            S.push(infix[i]);
        }
        else if (infix[i] == '('){
            S.push(infix[i]);
        }
            else if (infix[i] == ')'){
                while (!S.empty() && S.top() != '('){
                    temp += S.top();
                    S.pop();
                }
                S.pop();
            }
            else
                temp += infix[i];
        }
    while (!S.empty()){
        temp += S.top();
        S.pop();
    }
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you used the debugger, and single stepped (executing one statement at a time), which statement causes the issue?

Comment: What is the exact text of the runtime error (please edit your question with the text)?

Comment: else if (infix[i] == ')'){
                while (!S.empty() && S.top() != '('){
                    temp += S.top();
                    S.pop();
                }

S.pop()  that causes the runtime error